# (Unity) Is there a way to get notified when referenced object instance gets deleted/missed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

So let's say we have MonoBehaviour class with a Transform property:

```
public class Class : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target; //An object is already referenced here.
}
```

Question is simple: is there a way to get an event or some sort of callback in case this object gets deleted (externally)?

*Unity will show this as "Missing":*

[image: 1]

Since it is just a transform, you cannot really use `OnDestroy()` here, and even if you could this is not a good option because of how many transform instances there are.

Comment: Maybe [OnValidate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) when "a value changed in the inspector" ? Then use `tryGetComponent` ?

Comment: `OnValidate()` works only in editor, therefore is not an option.
`tryGetComponent` could work, but it will force script to check it each frame to be sure. It will do, I just think there could be a better solution.

Comment: Well then, make the Transform `private` and create public get/set functions - that way you can implement the required logic in the set function.

Comment: I tried, problem is whenever object gets destroyed via `Destroy(gameobject)` method, transform is deleted too, yet nothing is going inside "set" function since no one is setting `target = null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializable fields can be changed at runtime via editor inspectors, so compile time guarantees are not possible.

As adviced, you can do:

```
void OnValidate() {
    if (Target == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();    
}
```

You can also try, inspired in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.OnInspectorGUI.html) example (not debugged):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

// Creates a custom Label on the inspector for all the scripts named ScriptName
// Make sure you have a ScriptName script in your
// project, else this will not work.
[CustomEditor(typeof(Class))]
public class ClassEditor: Editor
{
    Class classInstance;
    protected void OnEnable() {
        classInstance = (Class)target;
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //you can first try only uncommenting line below to check if this script is working
        //GUILayout.Label ("This is a Label in a Custom Editor");  
        
        if (classInstance.Target === null) {
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Target transform missing");
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if the `Class` name can give a conflict, change the class name if so. Also not sure if the component is evaluated to `null` when its missing (null and missing are not the same), I think that code wise is the same and that the nullRef exception is thrown for both, but you are told in the console if its null or missing.
You can try that out. Hope it may at least gide you. Eventual problems are left as homework :)

Comment: then if you do a `if (classInstance.Target === null) Debug.Log("whatever")` or `Debug.LogError`, in the `Start()` of your script it will be shown in the [log files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) and you can call your code right there. Dont need an event/callback for that.

Comment: @FrankyDoll It's a bit rude to change the question after someone writes a correct and helpful answer to what it was originally, and make their answer invalid... Do you suppose you could revert the question to what this answer is for and ask this new question [in a separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: I think I am not getting the point of the question. You are not suposed to lose or manipulate the project once built, meaning that the situation of the resource being available when built and then not after built will not happen. So the error/callback should be triggered at the time you do the build/compile. `OnValidate`, or in-editor approaches should do the trick for you. I would find more interesting to be able to force a compile error in the case of a missing element which I dont believe it is possible...

Comment: There is a special `unity-editor` tag for editor questions I intentionally didn't use, but I will do as you prefer.